# How to write specific Azure resource information (tags on creation and deletion of resource) to Azure Log Analytics Workspace?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-resource-manager, azure-log-analytics

I try to write out resource information to a Log Analytics workspace. The concrete task is to write information of the address space taken up by resources in our subscription to a Log Analytics Workspace. Furthermore an automated workflow should be used using Terraform or an ARM template.

The options I see:

1. Custom Logs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-custom-logs)? The problem is here that I could only imagine the log files to be in an Azure storage account, because I would like to automate it via Terraform.
2. HTTP Data Collector API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api)?

What is the most appropriate approach for my task? - thank you!

Comment: If you want to use ARM template to collect  custom logs, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/template-workspace-configuration

Comment: echoing Jim Xu's comment above to explore [Resource Manager template samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/samples/resource-manager-workspace) for your scenario. Also recommend posting this and similar Azure-Monitor related questions directly to the "[Microsoft Q&A discussion forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/topics/single/24223.html)' for targeted guidance from Azure Monitor experts